# AWS Credential setup gives error in Windows Server

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

I am trying to set up my AWS on my local machine through windows PowerShell, it gives me the following error message;

```
Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXX -SecretKey = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA -StoreAs testuser

Set-AWSCredentials : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXX -SecretKey = AAAAAAAAAAA ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AWSCredentials], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Amazon.PowerShell.Common.SetCredentialsCmdlet
```

Please help:

Comment: Remove the `=` before each `XXXXXX`

Answer (score 0):

The equals sign is not required for a parameter.

From `Get-Help About_Parameters` :-

> Most Windows PowerShell commands, such as cmdlets, functions, and
>   scripts, rely on parameters to allow users to select options or
>   provide input. The parameters follow the command name and have the
>   following form:
>
> ```
> -<parameter_name> <parameter_value>
> ```

You are likely confusing setting a parameter with a variables, you would use the equals sign when assigning something to a variable:

```
$path = "C:\Windows\System32"
```